# javascript cross domain without jsonp and proxy

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

In our web application,we have do some ajax request,so we may meet the cross domain problem.

Since the we use the ajax to request the standard web service which return the xml document.

So we can not use the jsonp.

Also we do not want to use the proxy. Since the server may use the reverse proxy in which case the proxy may not work.

Then I want to know if there is any other way to slove this cross domain problem?

---

The service methioned here are standard ogc web service.

[An example.](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs)

[Another example](http://v2.suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&request=getCapabilities)

---

Update2:
We avoid using the proxy in that we have meet the problem when the server use the reverse proxy.

For example,the server address exposed is 'http://100.1.1.1'.

The I make a ajax requst:'http://100.1.1.1/proxy.ashx?url=http://100.2.2.2/xx.img'.

Then the server '100.1.1.1' foward this request to the local network whose ip my '192.168.1.1', then the proxy.ashx now can not access the internet '100.2.2.2'. so ... :(.
[image]

Comment: I still don't see *why* you can't use JSONP.

Comment: If I request the `http://server/service?xx=xx` Then I got a xml document. `<xml ../><xxx><xxxx/>` So I can not wrap the xml document in the callback.

Comment: Do you have control over the server? If yes, you can make it output JSONP (contrary to its name, the response does not have to include JSON at all).

Comment: @hguser: Your JSONP request can either request `http://server/jsonp?service=xx&xx`, which outputs the XML as a string parameter to the callback (`foo("<xml>...</xml")`), which you can then [parse in JavaScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), or you can detect the `&callback` parameter in your `http://server/service?xx=xx` and do the same  thing.

Comment: @Felix Kling,@Matt: we can not control the server,the service provided by the server has its standard which define the result of response.(xml document rather than the plain text). See my update.

Comment: @hguser: In which case you might be able to use something like [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to act as a proxy for you (untested).

Comment: Then you are just out of luck if you don't want to use a proxy...

Comment: @Felix Kling: I update it. Please have a check if possible.

Comment: Don't really understand your description, but that seems to be more of network configuration issue.

Comment: @FelixKling: I add an picture in the post. Hope you can understand me. :(

Comment: Still seems to be just a network configuration problem. Let 100.1.1.1 be the actual proxy and not the reverse proxy or allow proxy.ashx to access the internet... but this is out of the scope of this website as it is not programming related. You just have to set up your proxy structure properly (or use Yahoo! Pipes).

Comment: :(. avoiding make the  100.1.1.1  be the actual proxy,or let the proxy.ashx access the internet is why we use the reverse proxy to keep our app safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XHR2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) allows cross-origin requests. If the web service you’re fetching the data from allows [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), you could use that — although you should note that this is [only supported in](http://caniuse.com/cors):

- Chrome 3+
- Firefox 3.5+
- Safari 4+
- Internet Explorer 8+
- Opera 12+

Comment: Then you’ll have to use JSONP, or a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I used try to go with Flex + crossdomain.xml, or even JavaFX application to do some cross domain job